# Using MVC 2, try to get data based on returned list

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in .net 4.0 c#

I am trying to figure out how to get all the Tags.TagName for a given product

First I get the Tag by the TagId they select, then I do another select on the Products table and join ProductTags to find any product that is using the specified tag.

Now I have to get all the tags associated with each returned product from the previous list.

Table: Products

ProductId
title

Table: ProductTags

productId
tagId

Table: Tags

TagId
TagName

Comment: Are you using any ORM or just pure ADO.NET?

Comment: Could you clarify? This doesn't sound like anything to do with ASP.NET or MVC

Comment: Without a bit more clarity around what you're trying to do and what isn't working I suspect this question will end up being closed.

Comment: Trying to return a new list of data from the view based on the item.id..

Comment: I assume I need to use HTMLHelpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to create a new class based on ProductsViewModel and then add variable of type IEnumerable for a new TagViewModel class.

```
public IEnumerable<TagViewModel> tags { get; set; }
```